# Passing data from a 32-bit app to a 64 bit app?

Tags: c#

My company sells a data visualization tool.  Right not we do this with a 32-bit C# application (even though most of our clients have moved to 64-bit hardware) because it is almost impossible to get use the 64-bit Access drivers.

We would like to take advantage of a 64-bit application, but we don't want to put our clients through the pain of trying to getting connected to Access in a pure 64-bit environment.

So we had an idea.  What if we had a 32-bit background application running in the background that was responsible for pulling data out of Access.  This application would then pass the data to our main 64-bit application.

The thing we cannot sort out is how to pass the retrieved data from the 32-bit app to the 64-bit app.

Anybody got ideas of how to do this or have another approach we can take?

Comment: um... that shouldn't matter especially when dealing with Access for example. it doesn't matter if you use 64bit app, you can still use 32bit drivers but you cannot do 32bit and use 64 bit apps or drivers. I think you are overthinking and overcomplicating this :). In general, passing data from 32bit app to 64bit will work just fine. you just cant do it the other way around if using and dealing with 64bit values

Comment: Note: Normal inter-process communication pretty much works between 64 and 32 bit processes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Of course, I think Ben Voigt's suggestion of converting the data away from a dieing format is a good one.

Comment: Converting away from Access would be wonderful. But we have no control over data storage.  We are having to work with in-house databases.  Our customers are tied into a really old product that also uses the data.  This application's default datastore is Access. There are thousands of Access databases in our customers' offices.  We cannot force our customers to do something else.  We are stuck with trying to deal with situation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your customers would expect to use Jet database (MS Access) with 64-bit software.

I would:

- drop support for Jet from the 64-bit version
- provide a 32-bit conversion tool to turn Jet databases into some other format that is usable from 64-bit.  (This other format needs both 32-bit and 64-bit drivers, one for the conversion tool and the other for the main 64-bit app)

In essence what I'm saying is: pass the data from 32-bit to 64-bit by storing it into a different database format.  SQL Server Compact or SQLite should work well; they are file-based like Access but much more modern.

Comment: Inerestingly, the 64-bit ACE driver might be a poor choice given it precludes running 32-bit Office on the same machine.  So, your suggestion of SQL Server Compact or SQLite seems right on the nose.

Comment: See comment above --- unless we can support Access, we don't have a sellable product.

Comment: @user1753352: Well, you keep Access support in your 32-bit version, I never suggested otherwise.  It just so happens that Access databases are size limited, and there's really no advantage to going 64-bit on that small a database.